# list contain another list java ee

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, linked-list

i have table in database contain (id, Date, Category, line, duration) and i have for each day many registry for example 
(1, 12/12/2014, cat1, ligne1, 12) 
(2, 12/12/2014, cat2, ligne1, 10)
(3, 12/12/2014, cat3, ligne2, 23)

(4, 13/12/2014, cat1, ligne1, 10)
(5, 13/12/2014, cat2, ligne1, 20)
(6, 13/12/2014, cat2, ligne1, 30)

I want get this table from database to a table in page JSP organized by date, so every date has his own values.
I heard that i have to use linked list but i don't know how

Comment: are you going to use JDBC or JPA ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a customised class say MyClass as below:

```
public class MyClass {
    int id; 
    String category;
    String line;
    int duration;
    //getter and setter
}
```

Populate above class as and when you get data from DB and make them into a List as below:

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = new LinkedList<MyClass>();
.....//DB activities
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
//within while loop
myClass.setId(rs.get("id"));
....
myClassList.add(myClass);
//store this myClassList as request Attribute or call this method from JSP to get list of MyClass
```

And in jsp you could do something like:

```
<c:forEach var="myClass" items="${myClassList}">
<tr>
    <td>${myClass.id}</td>
     ...
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: what that means: rs.get("id")

Comment: its the resultset that you get when you do call db using jdbc.